# dojo filteringselect with ajax call - how to populate select box with returned values

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

I think I have got the difficult stuff done. I have got a form with 2 filtering select boxes. The first is populated by a hard coded array of 3 values (will make dynamic later). When I select the value, I have a json-rpc call go to my database and return me the values I want for the second box. Think of it like country selected USA — the database returns only American cities to populate second box.

This is my Javascript to populate the second text box:

```
function category_changed()
{
    var store = directoryBroker.getSubCategorys(document.getElementById('categoryId').value);
    store.addCallback(
        function (response)
        {
            var result = dojo.eval("(" + response + ")");
            if (typeof(result)!='undefined')
            {
                 document.getElementById('subCategoryId').disabled = false;
                 document.getElementById('subCategoryId').value = result[0].id;
            }
        }    
    );
}
```

This is the php for creating the form:

```
$category = new Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_FilteringSelect('categoryId');
    $category
        ->addMultiOption('a', '-- Please Select --')
        ->addMultiOptions($directoryModel->getAllCategorysForSelect())
        ->setValue('a')
        ->setRequired(true)
        ->setAttribs(
            array(
                'style' =>  'width: 400px',
                'onchange' => 'JavaScript: category_changed();'
            )
        )
        ->setLabel("Category:")
        ->addFilter('StringTrim')
        ->addValidator('int');


  $subCategory = new Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_FilteringSelect('subCategoryId');
    $subCategory
        ->addMultiOption('-1', '-- Select Category First --')
        ->setRequired(true)
        ->setAttribs(
            array(
                'disabled' => 'disabled',
                'onchange' => 'JavaScript: subCategory_changed();',
                'style' => 'width: 400px;'

            )
        )
        ->setLabel("Sub Category:")
        ->addValidator('int');
```

I have tried a few different ways of setting the value but it just wont seem to change... The result object looks like this:

```
result[0] "[{"name":"Test1","id":"1"}]"
```

All I want is `"Test1"` to be the value, I'm sure it's something simple but just cant see it!

Comment: Is the server response that "result[0]..." line? Are you sure you can't have your server return something more sane in that case?

Comment: result = dojo.eval("(" + response + ")") which is the json string returned from the server. What would be more sane?

Comment: Can you just give an example of how the JSON looks like? I think I didn't understand you very well.

Comment: it's shown above it is to the right of result[0]

Comment: Could you update your question with the relevant markup for your page?  Are instantiating your dijit widgets declaratively or programatically?

Comment: ok i have added my php form above now

Comment: @Pjn2020: something unrelated: are you sure you can't use `handleAs: 'JSON'` in your AJAX call instead of doing the eval?

Comment: possibly... i am getting the result i want back though i just need to display it now!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to do is change your calls to

```
document.getElementById('subCategoryId')
```

to a call that retrieves an instance of your actual dijit widget:

```
var secondaryFilteringSelect = dijit.byId('subCategoryId');
```

`document.getElementById` and `dojo.byId` only return the physical dom nodes of the elements, not the actual javascript widget object.  You want to use `dijit.byId`  instead.

Then, with that widget, you can use the widget's `set` function to set set its properties

```
secondaryFilteringSelect.set('disabled', false);
secondaryFilteringSelect.set('value', result[0].id);
```

Take a look at the [FilteringSelect API Docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dijit/form/FilteringSelect) for more information.

Also, for adding new options to the FilteringSelect based on the change in the first menu, you'll probably want to take a look at the FilteringSelect's inherited method [addOption](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dijit/form/Select#addOption)